# C# How to launch Chrome and make it perform a web request having Basic Authentication

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I'm trying to write C# code that launches chrome.exe to a specific web page, but my requirements involve opening a page that needs Basic Authentication. I am told to provide the Basic Authentication in the request header, and not in the URL. The C# code below launches chrome.exe:

```
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "http:\\www.anyurl.com";
        proc.Start();
```

But now, how do I make Chrome open a page with a specific request having Basic Authentication in the request header? I found the code below, but I don't know how to merge the two snippets.

```
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:51232/");
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36";
        webRequest.ContentLength = 0; // added per comment
        string autorization = "username" + ":" + "Password";
        byte[] binaryAuthorization = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(autorization);
        autorization = Convert.ToBase64String(binaryAuthorization);
        autorization = "Basic " + autorization;
        webRequest.Headers.Add("AUTHORIZATION", autorization);
        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        if (webResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) Console.WriteLine("{0}", webResponse.Headers);
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            reader.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Chrome doesn't natively support this. You would likely have to use a browser extension that your app talks to or use Selenium with addons such as [modheader_selenium](https://github.com/bewisse/modheader_selenium) and the [modheader extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en)

Comment: Do you control the page you are showing?  The usual way to go about this is to have some sort of auth token in the query string and having your web page consume that as an alternative authentication flow.

Comment: The page we are opening is controlled by another team in our organization, we are required to use Basic Authentication in the request header. Would it be possible to open a dummy web page and, using JavaScript, redirect to the appropriate page using the proper request header in JavaScript? If that is possible, I'd like to see how.